# Chromebook linux shell premission to write on SD Card or USB Stick

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, chromebook

I just both recently chromebook and I am super satisfied with it. All that I need (VS Code, Expo Go, NodeJS, Python etc.) working perfectly fine without single problem. Only problem that I can't sort is that I can not write anything on SD Card or USB Stick trough terminal. For example I can make new folders and files trought side bar in VS Code or trough Chromebook File Explorer but when I run any npm install inside folders I am getting `EACCES` error. If I create folder on internal memory and run for example `sudo npm install --save express` it works perfectly fine but when folder is on sd card or usb I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/mime
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I just want to be able to when I do not want to sit in front my pc that I can just take usb stick with project on and stick it to chromebook while on couche and continue where I stoped with all premissions. I can run project and write code but not intall any dependencies. My folder is shared with linux and I tried with `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` also without any luck.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it is a known bug, look at here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980456

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.